# How do I include a rich html file inside of Jade/Pug?

Tags: html, formatting, include, pug, stylesheet

So I'm trying to include a landing page that I've already coded in html in my Node.js project and I can't figure out how to include the html inside a jade file so that it formats correctly. I've tried rendering the html from index.js, but that didn't work, and translating the html to jade for index.jade, but that didn't work either.

My main problem is that when I load the html file directly onto my browser, it has the correct formatting and everything looks like it should, but when I use any of these methods, including where you just include the html file inside the jade file, the page is never formatted correctly.

I've tried looking for answers all over the place and I think the problem is possibly that jade does not allow you to insert a rich html file, only plain, which strips it of the formatting that I've already done. I'm not sure if this is the problem either, but my stylesheet that I am using is a translated scss.

index.jade

```
doctype html
link(rel='stylesheet', href='../public/stylesheets/profile_style.css')
include profiles.html
```

index.js

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log("It's coming in here idk");
    res.render('index');
});
```

profiles.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>FAUXFLIX</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/stylesheets/profile_style.css">


</head>

<body>
   etc....
```

So I guess my question is, is there a way to load up an html page and keep the formatting? Or does Jade/Pug simply not support the including of rich html/scss files?

Comment: what do you mean with rich html ? and why you are trying to insert html with `<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en" > ...` ? These block already defined in your jade file

Comment: have you tried only including the html inside the jade file. I mean there is only a single line in your jade file which is `include profiles.html`?